# How to Send bytes array in dataset and read from it

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, arrays

I want to send bytes in a data set and I have a column of data type varbinary(MAX). When i try to send a byte array, instead of showing a byte array in the data set it shows the below data. I don't know if it is a pure byte array or if it is showing bytes. What I was thinking the "ProjectIcons" column should return was a value like **{bytes[1305]}**....

1)If it is bytes then how can i read the bytes from dataset.[image]

Please let me know where I am wrong. I am using below code:

```
public DataSet GetAllProjectStandardIcons2()
    {
        var images = (from p in dbModel.tbl_STANDARDPROJECTICONS select new ProjectDetails1 
        {   
            id = p.id,
            ProjectIcons = (Byte[])(p.ProjectIcons)
        }).ToList();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        if (images.Count > 0)
            {
                Byte[] ProjectIcons;
                DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("id");
                DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("ProjectIcons");
                dt.Columns.Add(dc);
                dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
                for (var i = 0; i < images.Count(); i++)
            {

                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                row["id"] = images[i].id;
                ProjectIcons = (Byte[])images[i].ProjectIcons;
                row["ProjectIcons"] = ProjectIcons;
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        return ds;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try to Save image in Base64 Format and retrieve in same format, after that try to convert it in bytes...try following code

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.Count(); i++)
                {

                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                    row["id"] = images[i].id;
                    row["ProjectIcons"] = Convert.ToBase64String(images[i].ProjectIcons);//convert here byte array to base64
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

**I have found the solution Need to convert bytearray to base64 array below is the code that is working for me**

```
public DataSet GetAllProjectStandardIcons2()
        {
            var images = (from p in dbModel.tbl_STANDARDPROJECTICONS
                          select new ProjectDetails1
                          {
                              id = p.id,
                              ProjectIcons = (Byte[])(p.ProjectIcons)

                          }).ToList();


            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            if (images.Count > 0)
            {
                Byte[] ProjectIcons;
                DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("id");
                DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("ProjectIcons");
                dt.Columns.Add(dc);
                dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
                for (var i = 0; i < images.Count(); i++)
                {

                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                    row["id"] = images[i].id;
                    row["ProjectIcons"] = Convert.ToBase64String(images[i].ProjectIcons);//convert here byte array to base64
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            return ds;

        }
```